# Can't Detect Sony Xperia Miro in Eclipse

Tags: android, device-driver, device

I am unable to test Android app on Sony Xperia Miro. Its very easy to test on HTC devices but unable to find the solution for xperia miro. I am testing apps using the Android emulator all things are working fine, but xperia device is not detected, The device is detect for all other functionality like accessing sd card, internal memory, synchronization etc but cant find my device for debugging app. Please help me out.

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Have you enabled development mode?

Comment: @Rajesh yes but not working

Comment: Check whether it is being listed in `adb devices`. If not, the device may not be in debuggable (development) mode. You can also try restarting `adb`.

Comment: It is not on list but in debugable mode, please explore what to do, what necessary steps to be taken?

Comment: Restart device, restart `adb` using `adb kill-server` and then `adb start-server`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect your device and try restarting your server like so:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```